# Custom object search in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

To create child record, I use `e.force:createRecord` but when I type the name of parent record into look-up field, it shows nothing even whole name or some letter.
[image]

I want to have the functionality as standard object like contact:

[image]

Do I need to config somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Lightning shows only recently accessed records.

To have more flexibility you might need to create a completely custom component which would include custom lookup.

For my case I used custom components with custom lookup with similar approaches to [this post](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/07/custom-lookup-lightning-component/) or [this one](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html)